# Bootstrap Multiple Column Form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a 2 column contact form using bootstrap but I have this kind of difficulty where some of my `<div class="form-group">` didnt go as planned.

My desired output should be:

```
first name                         message
textbox                            textbox

last name                          submit button
textbox

email
textbox

contactno
textbox
```

Here's my code. My output for now is they are all in the left side and the textbox of message is small.

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>                 
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>                    
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactno">Contact No.</label>
    <input type="contactno" class="form-control" id="contactno" name="contactno" placeholder="Enter Contact No." required>               
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-5">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="message">Message</label>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>             
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">                
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" required="required">Submit Message</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have your second column nested inside your first, separate them and you should see the desired result.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fname">Name *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contactno">Contact No.</label>
        <input type="contactno" class="form-control" id="contactno" name="contactno" placeholder="Enter Contact No." required>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" required="required">Submit Message</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```